# Extract global float from code with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, regression

I am trying to extract all the global variable (eg: float) from a given code:

```
float aaa = 3.0;

float sat( float t ) {
  return clamp( t, 0.0, 1.0 );
}

float bbb = 3.0;

vec3 spectrum_offset( float t ) {
  float t0 = 3.0;
  return clamp( vec3( -t0, 1.0-abs(t0), t0), 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

My expect result are:

```
float aaa = 3.0;
float bbb = 3.0;
```

I tried with the following regex:

`^\s*float\s+.*\s*=\s*.*;`

[An online example in regexr.com](https://regexr.com/676mn)

which gives me the result:

```
float aaa = 3.0;
float bbb = 3.0;
float t0 = 3.0;
```

As you can see the last one `t0` is inside a function body so this one is the one should not be picked up.

How can I rule out the variable inside any function body leaving only the ones that are in the global area.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: To do something like this, in general, requires an actual JavaScript parser. You can't do it with a regular expression unless you're working with code that is constrained in some particular way.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this answer doesn't directly use Regular Expressions, I post this as an alternative solution to parsing what looks like GLSL code.

## Regular Expressions and parsing programming languages

Generally attempting to parse anything considered a programming language using Regular Expressions is a bad plan. This is due to the complexity of the languages i.e. things like comments, variable scope, escaping characters, etc.

It's always best to use a parser built to parse the language. There are generally parsers available for many languages that create an AST.

## Summary

- Use a parser built for the GLSL language to build an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree)
- Libraries used are [glsl-tokenizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glsl-tokenizer) and [glsl-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glsl-parser)
- The AST output object contains a `scope` property which contains a list of globals.
- Note that in the sample provided the function `sat` is also considered listed in the `scope`
- We filter this list looking for declaration lists with only `float` types.
- Note that the output AST `globals` variable includes line numbers and position of the globals found.

```js
var tokenString = require('glsl-tokenizer/string');
var parseTokens = require('glsl-parser/direct')

const code = `
float aaa = 3.0;

float sat( float t ) {
  return clamp( t, 0.0, 1.0 );
}

float bbb = 3.0;

vec3 spectrum_offset( float t ) {
  float t0 = 3.0;
  return clamp( vec3( -t0, 1.0-abs(t0), t0), 0.0, 1.0);
}
`;
const tokens = tokenString(code);
const ast = parseTokens(tokens)

function filterObject(obj, callback) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).
    filter(([key, val]) => callback(val, key)));
}
                  
const globals = filterObject(ast.scope, x => (
    x.parent.type === 'decllist' &&
    x.parent.parent.token.data == "float"
));

return globals;
```

## The output

You can view this code running here:
https://runkit.com/deanmarktaylor/find-global-variables-in-glsl-code

Here is example output objects, note the line number and position which might be useful.
[image]

## Further reading

If you are after doing more than just knowing where the variables are in the code and actually manipulating these found variables...
Instead of manipulating the string of the found global `float` variables you might find it best use the AST, adjust it and then generate the code from the AST.